# newrelic nginx plugin information is not being displayed

Tags: plugins, nginx, newrelic

I've been trying to get the Nginx newrelic nginx plugin installed and working:  http://newrelic.com/plugins/nginx-inc/13

Although it seems to be installed and running correctly, no data appears in the newrelic console.

I know that the nginx module is configured and working fine and the agent appears to be working as expected, and newrelic has recognized that the plugin is running and created a plugin section in the console.

When I run ./newrelic_nginx_agent in order to insure that there's no problems with the plugins I get output like this:

```
[root@nginx1:newrelic_nginx_agent]$ ./newrelic_nginx_agent
Faraday: you may want to install system_timer for reliable timeouts
[Fri Aug 02 21:01:27 UTC 2013] Agent Nginx is at version 1.0.1
active=39 accepts=4098 handled=4098 requests=12502 reading=20 writing=3 waiting=16
[Fri Aug 02 21:01:27 UTC 2013] Metrics for nginx1[com.nginx.newrelic-agent] for last 60 seconds:
[Fri Aug 02 21:01:28 UTC 2013]   Sent 4 metrics to New Relic [https://platform-api.newrelic.com]:
[Fri Aug 02 21:01:28 UTC 2013]     Component/Connections/Active[Connections]: count: 1, total: 39.0, min: 39.0, max: 39.0, sum_of_squares: 1521.0
[Fri Aug 02 21:01:28 UTC 2013]     Component/Connections/Reading[Connections]: count: 1, total: 20.0, min: 20.0, max: 20.0, sum_of_squares: 400.0
[Fri Aug 02 21:01:28 UTC 2013]     Component/Connections/Writing[Connections]: count: 1, total: 3.0, min: 3.0, max: 3.0, sum_of_squares: 9.0
[Fri Aug 02 21:01:28 UTC 2013]     Component/Connections/Waiting[Connections]: count: 1, total: 16.0, min: 16.0, max: 16.0, sum_of_squares: 256.0
[Fri Aug 02 21:01:28 UTC 2013] Gathered 4 statistics
```

A few seconds later I'll get additional output:

```
active=42 accepts=4176 handled=4176 requests=12735 reading=18 writing=1 waiting=23
[Fri Aug 02 21:03:27 UTC 2013] Metrics for nginx1[com.nginx.newrelic-agent] for last 60 seconds:
[Fri Aug 02 21:03:28 UTC 2013]   Sent 6 metrics to New Relic [https://platform-api.newrelic.com]:
[Fri Aug 02 21:03:28 UTC 2013]     Component/Connections/Active[Connections]: count: 1, total: 42.0, min: 42.0, max: 42.0, sum_of_squares: 1764.0
[Fri Aug 02 21:03:28 UTC 2013]     Component/Connections/Reading[Connections]: count: 1, total: 18.0, min: 18.0, max: 18.0, sum_of_squares: 324.0
[Fri Aug 02 21:03:28 UTC 2013]     Component/Connections/Writing[Connections]: count: 1, total: 1.0, min: 1.0, max: 1.0, sum_of_squares: 1.0
[Fri Aug 02 21:03:28 UTC 2013]     Component/Connections/Waiting[Connections]: count: 1, total: 23.0, min: 23.0, max: 23.0, sum_of_squares: 529.0
[Fri Aug 02 21:03:28 UTC 2013]     Component/Requests[Requests/Seconds]: count: 1, total: 1.8657934131562, min: 1.8657934131562, max: 1.8657934131562, sum_of_squares: 3.48118506057705
[Fri Aug 02 21:03:28 UTC 2013]     Component/Accepts[Connections/Seconds]: count: 1, total: 0.699672564900836, min: 0.699672564900836, max: 0.699672564900836, sum_of_squares: 0.489541698074914
[Fri Aug 02 21:03:28 UTC 2013] Gathered 6 statistics
```

And so on...

I haven't found any forum or git repo or anyplace I can get support on this.  Newrelic states that nginx would support it, but there's no support forum or even a link in regards to this plugin.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this might be debugged or fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I was just too impatient.  After reloading, I now see data in the console.

Comment: Under which tab you found the data?

Comment: the plugins tab will contain a new entry for NGINX.